# fan too high on new PC under windows 11

Tags: fan, cooling, overheating

I have an HP ALLIN ONE 27-d1000i (https://support.hp.com/be-fr/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-27-inch-all-in-one-desktop-pc-27-d1000i/2100364204/model/2100364214?sku=548R7EA)

PC purchased in January 2022. Delivered with windows 11.

Until today the fan is almost not running. But since today it works continuously on windows. no change since yesterday. When I am in the BIOS, it is quiet. So the problem only happens when windows is loaded.

No recent changes. The windows updates were all disabled (re-enabled today in the hope that it will solve the problem).

I use the computer only for simple things (like MS OFFICE..).

How do I know what is causing this overheating?

Screenshot of HWMonitor

[image: HWMonitor]

Comment: finally I found what's wrong. I killed the "Widget Windows" task and it immediately calmed the fan. The strange thing is that windows widgets are disabled in my settings so I didn't understand why this task was active?

Answer (score 1):

"**Windows widget**" was causing this problem. Detected in the TaskManager. Once killed, this solves the problem immediately.

"**Windows widget**" was always disabled. I don't know why it suddenly "woke up". Disabling it via the settings is not enough. The solution is to delete it completely:

Launch Powershell as Admin, then run:

```
winget uninstall "Windows web experience Pack"
```

then confirm with "**Y**"